# Query REST web service with Apache Spark?

Tags: rest, apache-spark

We have have some data on Hadoop that needs augmented with data only available to us via a REST service.  We're using Spark to search for, and correct, missing data. Even though there are a lot of records to scour for missing data, the total number of calls to the service is expected to be low, so it would be ideal to do the whole job in Spark as we scour the data.

I don't see anything obvious in the API or on Google relating to making REST calls from a Spark job.  Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing spark-specific for this, you can use your favorite java or scala HTTP library to make the call, probably in a map function which will return the input data and the data you retrieved from the service.